# Is there any way to create a class instance name by a string taken as user input?

Tags: c++, class

In C++, I want to create a class instance which name will be a string taken as input.

Consider the following code segment.

```
class my_class{
   int a;
};

int main()
{
   string name;
   getline(cin, name); //let the input "tom"

   my_class name; // expecting an instance of my_class named as tom
}
```

As it should, I am getting error. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: Identifiers are purely compile-time constructs, therefore they can never be  runtime-dynamic.

Comment: Fortunately the dupe shows you how to fake it out.

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for a `std::map<std::string, my_class>`. It's not possible in C++ to convert a runtime value to an object identifier (it's "name" in the code). You have to implement it yourself. `std::map` is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there any way to do it" - sure:

```
if (name == "foo") {
    /* Create a foo */
} else if (name == "bar") {
    /* Create a bar */
} // Etc ....
```